# jquery .load returned variable handling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have problem with my code. I use jQuery post for confirm that the name of filter is free for use.

```
$.post('check-username.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

When I use alert to show content of data, everything is fine.

But I need something like that:

```
$.post('check-username.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
if(data == 'ne'){
    alert('name allready taken');
}
});
```

But that wont work...

Here is my php code.

```
<?php
include("config.php");

$Sql = MySQL_Query("SELECT id FROM Filters where name = '".$_POST['name']."'");
if ( mysql_num_rows($Sql) != 0 ) {
   echo "ok";
}

else{
       echo "ne";
}
?>
```

Sorry for my english ;) Thanks for help

Comment: Concider SQL Injection. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php to prevent future surprises

Comment: Thx, this is only test code, that will be imported in final product.

Answer (score 0):

The if statement looks ok.

And if it looks ok when you alert the data - perhaps there is additional whitespace before or after "ne"  in your php page? Try adding an `exit`; statement after `echo "no";` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can get rid of those whitespaces. `data = data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); if(data=="ne")` should work